# Suggestions on structuring Hapi.js app that includes Models built with bookshelf.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I'm working on a small app and I am integrating `bookshelf.js` as the ORM. The one piece I am struggling with is structuring my app so that I can `require` other models without having to Inject them when creating each other model.

For Example:

Middleware Plugin:

```
'use strict';

var Knex = require('knex');

exports.register = function(server, options, next) {
    var knex = Knex({
        client: 'mysql',
        connection: server.settings.app.mysql
    });
    var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);

    server.expose('bookshelf', bookshelf);

    next();
};

exports.register.attributes = {
    pkg: require('./package.json')
};
```

Model:

```
'use strict';

var Bluebird = require('bluebird');
var bcrypt = Bluebird.promisifyAll(require('bcrypt'));
var InvalidPasswordError = require('create-error')('InvalidPasswordError');


module.exports = function(bookshelf) {
    var User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
        tableName: 'user'
    }, {
        login: Bluebird.method(function(email, password) {
          return new this({email: email.toLowerCase().trim()})
            .fetch({require: true})
            .tap(function(user) {
                return bcrypt.compareAsync(password, user.get('encrypted_password'))
                    .then(function (matches) {
                        if (!matches) throw new InvalidPasswordError();
                    })
                })
            })
    });

    return User;
};
```

How I call it in the route:

```
var bookshelf = server.plugins['bookshelf'].bookshelf;
var User = require('../models/user')(bookshelf);

server.route([
    {
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/auth/login',
        config: {
            auth: false,
            payload: { allow: 'application/json' },
            handler: function(request, reply) {
                var email = request.payload.email;
                var pwd = request.payload.password;

                User.login(email, pwd).then(function(user) {
                    reply(user.pick('api_token'));
                }).catch(User.NotFoundError, function() {
                    reply(Boom.badRequest('Invalid Email', 400));
                }).catch(function(err) {
                    reply(Boom.badRequest('Invalid Password', 400));
                });
            },
            validate: {
                payload: Joi.object().keys({
                    email: Joi.string().email().required(),
                    password: Joi.string().required()
                })
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

The piece that I am confused about is setting up the Associations that will exist in my `User` model. For example, a User has many projects through a join table. But if I wanted to setup that association, I'd have to first pass in my `bookshelf` object to each model (Project and UserProject), then pass in the Association model (UserProject) to each User and Project.

That doesn't seem very clean. It could get messy super quick. Anyone else have suggestions and/or experience in structuring a Hapi.js or Node app with an ORM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [`registry` plugin](https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/wiki/Plugin:-Model-Registry)
. As the plugin docs state, you have to be sure that your model is required somewhere so that `bookshelf.model` is called.

```js
// db/index.js

var _ = require('lodash');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var models = require('require-dir')('./models');
var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knexClient);

bookshelf.plugin('registry');

for (var model in models) {
  models[model] = models[model](_, Promise, bookshelf);
}

module.exports = models;

// db/models/User.js

module.exports = function (_, Promise, bookshelf) {

  var User = bookshelf.model('User', {

    tableName: 'users',

    projects: function () {
      return this.hasMany('Project');
    }

    // more proto props or relations
  },
  {

    // constructor props
  });

  return User;
};


// db/models/Project.js

module.exports = function (_, Promise, bookshelf) {

  var Project = bookshelf.model('Project', {

    tableName: 'projects'

  },
  {

  });

  return Project;
};
```

You can require the models in your routes and the relations will be all hooked up. The `projects` collection can be queried through the `User` model. Below I'm using [fetchOne](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-fetchOne).

```
// route.js
var User = require('../db').User;

module.exports = function (app) {

  app.get('/projects/:projectId', function (req, res) {

    return User
      .forge({ id: req.auth.userId })
      .projects()
      .query({where: { id: req.params.projectId } })
      .fetchOne()
      .then(function (project) {

        res.send(project);
      });

  });

};
```